# Dot Net Core being Inconsistent

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core-3.0

I have a problem in my application that when `GetCustomAttributes` is called on the assembly Sigil v4.7, it throws an exception.

But this only occurs in a specific situation.  If Sigil v4.7 is added via Jil v2.15.4 then it will happen.

If you add Sigil v4.7 directly it does not repro.  Similarly if you add the latest version of Jil (v2.17.0), which still references Sigil v4.7, it does not repro.

I am stumped as to why, given the same dll, I would get different results.

Here is my test code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsAssemblyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sigilAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Contains("Sigil"));

            try
            {
                var attrs = sigilAssembly?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute), false)
                                          .OfType<AssemblyProductAttribute>();

                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>  Success: " + sigilAssembly?.GetName());
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>  Failed: " + sigilAssembly?.GetName() + " with " + exception.Message);
            }

            // This is here so the compiler does not remove the reference to Sigil.
            var createReferenceToSigil = Sigil.OptimizationOptions.All;    
        }
    }
}
```

To recreate this issue, create a .net core console app and add the above code to the `program.cs`.  Then add a NuGet reference to Jil v2.15.4 and run.  The Debug window will show:

> >>>>>>  Failed: Sigil, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2d06c3494341c8ab with Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

If you then upgrade to Jil v2.17.0 you will see this:

> >>>>>>  Success: Sigil, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2d06c3494341c8ab

**Why would the same version of the dll Sigil fail for one version of Jil and not for another?**

Comment: Maybe the Windows Folder Rights are messed up? It does that from time to time, with updates. One of the most extreme cases was when my Firefox could not raed it's *own profile directtory*, while something had messed up the rights on that folder. A simple reset of my entire use profile rights to "this user and admin, everything" fixed it.

Comment: @john - The assembly is found.  It just fails when it tries to call GetCustomAttributes on it.

Comment: @Christopher - I don't think it would be rights, because I can access it both times.  Just one gives a PInvoke missing exception and the other does not.

Comment: Did you compare dependency lists for each versions? There is a good chance that 15 just did not include whatever brings "System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke" as dependency and none of other packages you have nor main project brought it in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with Sigil. As you mentioned in your comment, it finds Sigil just fine, but fails on `GetCustomAttributes`.

And that's the problem: `GetCustomAttributes` relies on `System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke`.

So why can it find `PInvoke` when you're using Jil v2.17.0 but not v2.15.4?

Look at the dependencies of both [Jil v2.17.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jil/2.17.0) and [Jil v2.15.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jil/2.15.4). The difference is that 2.17.0 supports .NETStandard 2.0, but v2.15.4 only supports .NETStandard 1.6.

It's hard to find something that nails this down as exactly the problem, but if you search for ["System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke" "GetCustomAttributes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke%22%20%22GetCustomAttributes%22) you will find several results that explain that `System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke` was not available in .NET Core 1.0. (it was in the release candidate, but [removed before release](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10713#issuecomment-239649372))

So I believe what's happening is that if you use the newer package, it's running under .NETStandard 2.0 and `PInvoke` is available.